# setcookie not working with an array of string for $value argument

Tags: php, arrays, arguments, argument-passing, setcookie

I am trying to do this:

```
setCookie('visitor', array(0 => 'one', 1 => 'two'), time()+3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
```

But I am unable to get it work. The php reference explains "$value as string[optional]" which (as far as my understanding goes) should accept an array of string as argument. Please help me achieve something similar to this or correct me if my understanding of the php reference ( string[optional] ) is wrong.

Here is the setcookie function declaration:

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
```

Comment: Cookie values have to be strings. Pack your data into a string, for example, with `json_encode`.

Comment: Consider storing this data in your session or database. Cookies should be used as key container (to the session file or database entry) only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `serialize(array(0 => 'one', 1 => 'two'))` instead.

Use `unserialize()` when retrieving the array again.

And no: If the php manual says that the functions wants a string... Then they mean a string. Not an array of strings.

Maybe you are fooled by the [optional]? The square brackets don't mean anything. The whole "[optional]" thing just means that the function can be called without this parameter.

Comment: Okay this thing worked. But can you explain me what this string[optional] notation means? And how am I supposed to pass an array as an argument in php?

Comment: First question: Added to my answer. Second question: Your way of doing it would be totally correct of setCookie would accept an array. It's just that this function does not accept an array.

Comment: Well okay. What if the reference said string[] ?  That would have meant that I can pass an array of string. Right???

Comment: @Spoilt: The php way of specifying that is actually to just write "array" and to not specify the type of elements within the array.

Comment: @Spoilt: No. Just plain "array". Check for example: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php. The first parameter needs to be an array of string. The textual parameter description tells you. But the in the specification line it just says plain "array".

Answer (score 1):

If the `setcookie()` function did allow you to overload type, it would do so by passing the array into a loop. Since it doesn't support arrays, I'd use a foreach loop outside the function.

```
foreach (array(0 => 'one', 1 => 'two') as $key => $value) {
    setcookie('visitor[' . $key . ']', $value, time()+3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
)

var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

This results in...

```
array(1) {
    ["visitor"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "one"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "two"
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to be careful that `$key` doesn't contain a `]` or something else that could break it.